# Visual Studio Task Window - awaiting vs blocked Tasks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In the Tasks Window, while debugging, what is the difference between a Task whose status is "blocked" vs "awaiting"?

[image: Some Tasks Blocked, some tasks Awaiting]

I am trying to make sense of a "bad version"'s memory dump with thousands of tasks (scheduled, awaiting, blocked), and the Microsoft documentation does not seem to provide any differentiation between the blocked and awaiting statuses, in my understanding.

Extract from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-tasks-window?view=vs-2019

> An awaiting or blocked task is one that is blocked because it is waiting on an event to be signaled, a lock to be released, or another task to finish.

I'll focus on synchronization mechanisms while I dig through the code, to see if I can find differences and an explanation.

Meanwhile, I thought someone might already know, and I did not find any similar questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft documentation you cited explains "blocked" very clearly:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-tasks-window
>
> A blocked task is one that is blocked because it is waiting on an
> event to be signaled or a lock to be released

This is "classic blocking I/O", like the behavior of a C language "read()".

"Awaiting", on the other hand, implies [async/await](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/4240/your-ultimate-async-await-tutorial-in-c/introduction).

Here's a great article on the subject: [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Comment: I'm confused, the exact quote you have posted does not exist on the page, only the one I had provided in the question: "An awaiting or blocked task [...]", which to me means "either of the two". However, what you have said was my suspicion and it does make sense. I did notice a lock somewhere deep in one of the "blocked" call stacks. I'll upvote and accept once I confirm. Although I am familiar with Asynchronous programming I always appreciate a good read. Thanks for the links!

Comment: Ah! I see what you did there, comparing the quotes, I wish I could double upvote =)) Very clear indeed. Thanks for the answer, good sir!

Comment: Just confirmed, it was the lock! Thanks again!